# "the given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (exception from hresult: 0x80131047)"

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, hresult

I'm facing the exception "the given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (exception from hresult: 0x80131047)".
The .net application where there is a button to generate documents, when i click that button the documents should be generated. There is the sharepoint path to convert the documents.

Do suggest your opinion.

Check Assembly Loading Method:

If you are using Assembly.Load() to load a file, try changing it to Assembly.LoadFile() instead1.
Ensure that the assembly name provided is valid and corresponds to the correct assembly.
Remove Apostrophes from Project Name:

If your project name contains an apostrophe (e.g., “DBZ buu’s Fury Text Editor”), it might cause issues. Remove the apostrophe from the project name in the project properties1.
Verify Platform Target CPU:

Sometimes, the error can be related to the platform target CPU.
Check if the platform target CPU is set to “Any” instead of 64-bit or 32-bit1.

I have tried this all..